# Android ID associated with familiar devices

Tags: android-id

I have a **rooted** Moto e6 that I'm trying to change the Android ID on to one from a previous phone that is no longer serviceable. **This is not about app ID's, which have already been answered.** I'm attempting to recover a couple accounts and do not have the phone number I used when I set them up. Just being on a familiar network and knowing the previous passwords isn't enough any more, and since they shut down the "can you provide us with more information," I'm stuck trying to make a familiar device from scratch.

I downloaded my data from the one account I still own that was on that phone. This includes the 19-digit Android ID associated with the original device, as well as other device info such as the serial number, IMEI, etc.

I'm under the impression that's the Android ID Google uses to identify "familiar devices." I've looked and verified it's the same across different accounts on the same phone under the same user.

Going from another answer in here, I pulled up `/data/system/users/0/settings_ssaid.xml` on my Moto e6 and
the `android_id` shows up as a 64 bit hex string. I tried searching for the 19 digit number on the phone with Total Commander, but came up with nothing.

Yesterday I decided to try and swap out the 64 bit hex string with the 19 digit Android ID from the old phone, rebooted, pulled the device configuration data, and nothing changed. Still showing the same ID. I pulled it again this morning and, again, same.

My question is: Where is this number located? Am I looking in the wrong place?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your phone rooted? If not searching with Total Commander is a waste of time because as an app it can not access private files of other apps and system apps. Have you checked the other questions on ANDROID_ID? Such as https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47184/2241 BTW: When talking about IDs it is a good ide to present some samples (just change a few numbers), otherwise when you talk about  a "64bit" or "19 digit" ID it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: I made edits to the original post based on your suggestions; bolded the word rooted, added a picture showing what number I was talking about. As I mention I changed the 64 bit hex string to the 19 digit number I mentioned, so it's not there anymore. Above I put the location...

Comment: For some reason you can only edit a comment for 5 minutes...

I went back and rechecked. The 64 bit number was listed under "userkey" in `secure_ssaid`. I assumed because of the location and it being the only 64 bit hex that that was what I was looking for, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the hex number to a decimal number? If both are the same it doesn't matter which one you are searching for. There are also apps in Play Store which can set ANDROID_ID with root permissions.

Comment: Edit 2: Added a screenshot of the 64-bit hex string. It's not the original, I added a user to the phone then logged onto it with a different account so it would generate a new one.

Comment: I tried converting it a hundred different ways. Nothing comes up.